# Odata Controller: How to convert Odata response to C# object at client

Tags: c#, json.net, odata

We have got a Odata response as below:

```
"{\r\n  \"@odata.context\":\"http://localhost/ApplicationService/model/$metadata#Edm.String\",\"value\":\"{\\\"Messages\\\":[\\\"message 1\\\",\\\"message 2\\\",\\\"message 3\\\",\\\"message 4\\\"],\\\"IsValidEntity\\\":false}\"\r\n}"
```

Now say we have a class:

```
    public class myValidationResult
    {
        public myValidationResult()
        {
            Messages = new List<string>();
        }
        public List<string> Messages { get; set; }
        public bool IsValidEntity { get; set; }
    }
```

This class used in `MyOdataController` class as below:

```
public class MyODataController : ODataController 
{
        [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(T entity)
        {
                myValidationResult  vResult = new myValidationResult();
                vResult.Messages.Add("message 1");
                vResult.Messages.Add("message 2");
                vResult.Messages.Add("message 3");
                vResult.Messages.Add("message 4");
                vResult.IsValidEntity = false;

                 var strResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vResult);
                var resp = Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, strResult );

                return resp;
        }
}
```

For the client Consuming this, we created below Class:

```
public class OData<T> 
{
    [JsonProperty("odata.context")]
    public string Metadata { get; set; }
    public T value { get; set; }
}
```

In the method where we call the Odata method & store response in 'msg':

```
var resp = msg.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

`resp` is:

```
"{\r\n  \"@odata.context\":\"http://localhost/ApplicationService/model/$metadata#Edm.String\",\"value\":\"{\\\"Messages\\\":[\\\"message 1\\\",\\\"message 2\\\",\\\"message 3\\\",\\\"message 4\\\"],\\\"IsValidEntity\\\":false}\"\r\n}"


var odatares = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OData<myValidationResult>>(resp);
```

But the above line giving error:

```
Can not convert value\":\"{\\\"Messages\\\":[\\\"message 1\\\",\\\"message 2\\\",\\\"message 3\\\",\\\"message 4\\\"],\\\"IsValidEntity\\\":false}  to <.....namespace......>myValidationResult
```

Please suggest accordingly.

Comment: Please fix your formatting, it is hard to make out what is what.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The OData response contains a string, not an instance of `myValidationResult`. Also, the response looks like it's missing some backslashes. (Are you sure the response shown is *exactly* what you received from the service?)

You can either fix the serialization of `myValidationResult` on the service:

```
// Don't serialize vResult yourself. OData will do it for you.
var resp = Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, vResult );
```

Or deserialize in two steps as follows.

```
var data = "{\r\n \"@odata.context\":\"http://localhost/ApplicationService/model/$metadata#Edm.String\",\"value\":\"{\\\"Messages\\\":[\\\"message 1\\\",\\\"message 2\\\",\\\"message 3\\\",\\\"message 4\\\"],\\\"IsValidEntity\\\":false}\"\r\n}";
var outer = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OData<string>>(data);
var inner = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<myValidationResult>(outer.value);
```

One more thing: The `JsonProperty` on `OData<T>` should be named `@odata.context`.

Comment: Thanks for reploy: I Already tried object (vResult) initially but getting below response & can not get expected result at clietn:  Id = 0x00000003, Status = RanToCompletion, Method = "{null}", Result = "StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent, Headers:\r\n{\r\n  Pragma: no-cache\r\n  Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n  Date: Wed, 06 Jan 2016 07:04:25 GMT\r\n  Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5\r\n  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319\r\n  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET\r\n  Content-Type: application/json; odata.metadata=minimal\r\n  Content-Length: 97\r\n}"

Comment: Looks like the user making the request does not have the Admin role per the `Authorize` attribute on your `Post` method.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the OData response did not contain a string but an object array which contains the data string as its first element. So in this case reading the data should look like this:

```
var outer = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OData<object[]>>(data);
var inner = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<myValidationResult>(outer.value[0].ToString());
```