# Odata Controller: Content () method behaving unexpected when pass C# object entity as input

Tags: odata

I am trying to pass an C# object in Odatacontroler Content method:

```
var resp = Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, vResult );
```

Where vResult is a C# object with two fields (List Messaages; bool IsValidEntity) .

At client when I tried getting response bellow unexpected response coming:

> Id = 0x00000003, Status = RanToCompletion, Method = "{null}", Result =
>   "StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content:
>   System.Net.Http.StringContent, Headers:\r\n{\r\n  Pragma: no-cache\r\n
>   Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n  Date: Wed, 06 Jan 2016 07:04:25 GMT\r\n 
>   Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5\r\n  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319\r\n 
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET\r\n  Content-Type: application/json;
>   odata.metadata=minimal\r\n  Content-Length: 97\r\n}"

For details below can be referenced:
[Odata Controller: How to convert Odata response to C# object at client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614233/odata-controller-how-to-convert-odata-response-to-c-sharp-object-at-client#comment56998072_34622979)

Comment: "StatusCode: 401" => "Unauthorized".. nothing to do with (de-)serialization of the object. Are you going cross domain? Do you send (required?) security headers?

Comment: With same setting if i Replace the line with:                                                     var strResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vResult);
                var resp = Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, strResult );    everything works fine.  my question is why in case we do not serialize but pass directly C# object then why it says 'unauthorised' ReasonPhrase